# Magento - conditionals in layout files

Tags: magento

Is it possible in Magento to conditionally add blocks into a layout xml file?

Im thinking along the lines of having an admin config option checkbox - if checked then a block needs to be added to the page and vice versa if not checked.

I could think of a way of doing this via code but not the actualy layout file system itself.

Answer (score 3):

The `ifconfig` paramater can be used to conditionally call an action method

```
<action method="someBlockMethod" ifconfig="path/to/config"><param1>value</param></action>
```

The `path/to/config` path is passed to Mage::getStoreConfigFlag() to return a boolean.

I'd try using this in combination with the `insert` method

```
<action method="insert" ifconfig="path/to/config"><param>block_name</param></action>
```

The block with the name or alias of `block_name` will need to be already inserted into the layout object by other PHP or XML, so you may need to take additional steps to unset it from its original blocks after inserting it into your new block.

Comment: Thanks Alan - this looks very promosing.  Can I just check though if there is a more natural way of doing what I am trying to achieve.  Basically, if one of my modules config options is selected as yes (a yes no backend type) then I want to include a certain element on the product pages.

Comment: Im looking for something very similar to the paypal module - where you can select from the admin area to not show a logo.  I just cant figure out how the _toHtml() in the Logo.php block is working.

Comment: Thanks @Alan, I'd forgotten that it only works with actions and believed it could be used anywhere.

Comment: @clockworkgeek easy enough mistake to make, given Magento ships with an XML file that includes it in a block

Answer (score 1):

you can try this (i haven't tried it myself):

```
<action ifconfig='your/extension/active'
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, ifconfig only works with the <action nodes.  It will not prevent a block from being added (see source of app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php, which is the only PHP file that contains a reference to ifconfig)

Comment: as i said I have not tested this and only grepped for this from layout files

Comment: @Alan Storm, do you know if there is a solution, similar to the ifconfig?

Comment: @david see my answer for possible approaches http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852201/magento-conditionals-in-layout-files/5861635#5861635